# Upload image via ajax in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, upload

I have a little problem with code.

I can't receive input image in my controller. Then I use `print_r($input);` I receive empty array.

My js code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#photo-upload #upload-button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

        url: "/photo/upload/",
        data: new FormData($("#photo-upload")[0]),
        dataType:'json',
        type:'GET',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function ( data ) {

            alert("succes!");
        },

        error: function ( data ) {

            alert("error");

        }
    });
});
```

my form:

```
            <div class="full-cell">

                <span>Название</span>
            </div>

            <div class="full-cell">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="input-full" id="name">
            </div>

            <div class="full-cell">

                <span>Описание</span>
            </div>

            <div class="full-cell">
                <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="full-cell">

                <span>Загрузить в альбом:</span>

                <select name="album" id="album">

                    @foreach ($albums as $album)
                        @include('partials.select._album_names')
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="file">

                <input type="file" name="image" id="fileInput"/>
            </div>

            <div class="window-footer">

                <button type="button" class="auth-button btn-sec" id="upload-cancel">Отмена</button>
                <button type="submit" class="auth-button btn-advanced" id="upload-button" hidden="">Загрузить</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $user = Auth::user();                                                           //Данные учетной записи
    $input = Input::all();
    $image = Input::file('image');                                                  //Записываем картинку в переменную

    print_r($input);

    $filename  = $user->username . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();      //Создаем новое имя файла

    $date = date('Y-m-d');                                                          //Получаем дату
    $path = "user_data/photos/$date/";                                              //Создаем путь до оригинала
    $thumbnail_path = "user_data/photos/$date/thumbnail/";                          //Создаем путь до миниатюры

    File::makeDirectory("$path", 0775, true, true);                                 //Директория для фото
    File::makeDirectory("$thumbnail_path", 0775, true, true);                       //Директория для миниатюры

    $image->move($path, $filename);                                                 //Сохраняем картинку на сервер


    $photo = "$path" . $filename;                                                   //Адрес фото
    $thumbnail = "$thumbnail_path" . $filename;                                     //Адрес миниатюры

    File::copy($photo, $thumbnail);                                                 //копируюм фото в миниатюры

    $image = Image::make($thumbnail)->fit(153,90)->save();

    $new_photo = new Photo;

    $new_photo->owner_id    = $user->id;
    $new_photo->name        = $input['name'];
    $new_photo->description = $input['description'];
    $new_photo->photo       = "/$photo";
    $new_photo->thumbnail   = "/$thumbnail";
    $new_photo->album_id    = $input['album'];

    $new_photo->save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Code

```
  var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file",$('#fileForm16')[0].files[0]);
            formData.append("password",$("#textPassword").val());

  $.ajax({
                    url: "{{url("api/uploadfiles")}}",
                    data: formData,
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
                    processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
                    // ... Other options like success and etc

                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);


                    }
                });
```

Laravel Code

```
 if (($request->hasFile('file'))) {
            $destinationPath = 'uploads/files'; // upload path
            $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension

            $tempName = $request->file("file")->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = uniqid("MW") . '.' . $extension; // renameing image
            $request->file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
            // sending back with message
            $imagepath = $destinationPath.'/'.$fileName;


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution of this problem! i need use diferent even on my upload button.
i did use this event: 
$(document).on('click', '#photo-upload #upload-button', function(e) - and this not work!
now i use this event: 
$(document).on('submit', '#photo-upload', function(e) and code work fine!!! thx for all. Hope this will help anybody)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the Request instead.

```
$request->all()
```